# How to transpose copied data?

Tags: excel, vba

I want to transpose data, copied from "Sheet1" to "sheet2", from horizontal to vertical.

I can copy the data. How do I transpose it?

```
Sub sbCopyRangeToAnotherSheet()
    Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A1:G1").Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet2").Range("A1")
End Sub


Sub sbTranspose()
    Dim MyArray As Range
    Worksheets("Sheet2").Range("A1:E1").Formula = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:A40").Formula)
End Sub
```

This is the data:
[image]

I want it to be like so:
[image]

Comment: look into range.paste_special.

Answer (score 0):

i fixed it by using

```
    Sub Transpose_ex1()
Range("H1:I10").Value = WorksheetFunction.Transpose(Range("A1:F3"))
End Sub
```